# Does the different coloured solar system mean anything

Tags: no-mans-sky

On the universal map, the solar systems have different colours.  When i first began, it appeared that i couldn't get to a green or blue system without a sigma or tau hyperdrive booster.   Now that i have the different booster, I moved to a green system, but I don't notice any difference.  Has anybody noticed a difference between colours of solar systems or is it purely a light-year distance restriction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have seen a topic about this on the Steam forum and apparently the color coding works as follows:

- Yellow systems = basic difficulty with normal items
- Red systems (sigma upgrade needed) = medium difficulty with rare items
- Green systems (tau upgrade needed) = hard difficulty with higher chance or rare items
- Blue systems (theta upgrade needed) = extreme difficulty with highest chance of rare items

The difficulty has to do with the environments on the planets and space I assume. Never been to another color system myself though...

Comment: Do you have a link to the steam thread?

Comment: Will have to search for it again because I can't access steam from work.