# Star said I needed Sigma, but I had the Theta upgrade?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I went to visit a Red star and the system indicated that I needed the Sigma Warp drive.

I find this request strange as I already had the Theta upgrade (highest warp drive).

Why would it require me to have a lower end warp drive when I already have the highest upgrade?

Perhaps this is like trying to fly from my house to the corner store in a leer jet versus a bicycle, or are there other factors I'm not considering?

Comment: Does it really say you need a specific upgrade to reach a certain star? I my personal experience I have only noticed the game saying that I needed to upgrade my Warp drive to get to that star... If I'm not mistaken the highest is Omega for every upgrade and not Theta?

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks I believe the highest warp is Theta (unless I'm wrong). I had Theta, and it required me to have Sigma installed.

Comment: Don't know for sure if that is the highest warp since I, myself, haven't discovered that upgrade yet but on some other upgrades I did discover the Omega upgrade. Therefor I thought it could be a game bug that it actually needed the Omega drive but said Sigma drive instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look at [Does the different coloured solar system mean anything](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282340/does-the-different-coloured-solar-system-mean-anything/282341#282341)?, the answer goes into detail that each colored star system requires a specific Warp Reactor to get to.

This is mere speculation, but instead of it being a matter of "*perhaps this is like trying to fly from my house to the corner store in a leer jet versus a bicycle*", it is more-or-less a preventative for players to farm-hunt for the [Warp Reactor Theta](http://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Warp_Reactor_Theta) and be able to travel through the entire galaxy with a single Warp Reactor upgrade; especially for those who happen to find the Warp Reactor Theta as their first upgrade

Comment: I did see that answer. I guess it's possible to prevent people from visiting every star without 3 warp drives. However, to me that seems a bit ridiculous. What if I want to put 3 Theta drives to jump farther? I should be allowed to access a nearby star (regardless of color) based on the upgraded warp drive. Perhaps it's because the star emits certain types of energy and only certain warp drives can enter that field?